# Can Cassandra nest Sets of UDTs?

Tags: java, scala, cassandra, user-defined-types

I have a Cassandra schema with a table that has a column that is a SET of a user defined type (UDT).  That UDT itself has a column that is a SET of another UDT.
I **can** create the types and table in cqlsh but when I try to use this schema in my Java (actually Scala) code I get a "missing codec error".

Does anyone know if the Datastax java driver supports this?

`CREATE TYPE testname(firstname text, lastname text);
CREATE TYPE testuser(testname <FROZEN<SET<FROZEN<testname>>>);
CREATE TABLE testobjects(
  simplename text
  testusers SET<FROZEN<testuser>>
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (simple name DESC);`

I've registered codecs for the two UDT types but when I try to bind a prepared statement I get the error:

`can't find code for:
  cqlType: frozen<set<frozen<testname>>
  javaType: TestNameUDT`

Because while there is a codec mapping testname to TestNameUDT there really is no codec mapping a Set of testname's to a TestNameUDT.

So, I'm wondering if anyone knows if the Java driver supports this...has anyone created nested sets of UDTs?  Thanks.

Comment: which cassandra version is that?

Comment: also what's the stacktrace for the exception?

Comment: com.datastax.cassandra.dse-driver1.1.0 com.datastax.cassandra.cassandra-driver-mapping 3.1.1

It fails at com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry.createCodec (line 526)

Comment: Can you please share the model classes you have (those two `@UDT` and `@Table`)

Answer (score 0):

Datastax has acknowledged that this is a Cassandra defect and does not currently work.

Answer (score 0):

with spring data cassandra yes, but the nested udt must be declered without @cassandraType

https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS-506

hope it helps